# Correct javascript syntax for function

Tags: javascript

I've been looking to at some old javascript on a website I run - hands up, I know very little about javascript.

I came across the following function:

```
var timeout = null;

function textareaResize() {
    if (typeof(timeout))
        clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        refreshAutoGrowFields();
    }, 200);
}
```

The intellisense tells me that the syntax `typeof(timeout)` is invalid, to be more specific 'unexpected constant condition', however this means nothing to me.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain what should actually be there (if the intellisense is correct in its assumptions).

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function, but always returns a string, therefore `typeof anyting` will always evaluate to true in an if test - try, `if (timeout !== null)` instead

Comment: `typeof` is an operator and works without parenthesis.

Comment: @NinaScholz it also sometimes works with parenthesis too tho why is there an error here

Comment: you could wrap anything in parenthesis without error.

Comment: @NinaScholz even `return("value")` or `var("value")` ?

Comment: @bluejayke, for expressions. `var ...` is a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where that function was found, but it's definitely confusing, because it's actually inaccurate JavaScript.

What it's trying to do is make whats called a timeout, meaning a performance of a certain action or collection of code after a period of time.

In order to do this, it's attempting to set this "timeout" function to a pre-defined variable called "timeout".

The thing is, before they are setting it to the variable "timeout", for some reason they want to make sure that timeout hasn't already been set. Perhaps by setting it twice to setTimeout, it would potentially cause multiple functions to happen within the same amount of time (but perhaps not).

Anyways, in order to do that, they were trying to check if "timeout" has been set before.

The problem is the way they are checking it `typeof(timeout)`, is completely incorrect, for 2 reasons.

First, the term "typeof" isn't usually to be used like a [function call](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/function+call); rather, it is a keyword, much like `var` or `return`, so it shouldn't in general be used with `()`s like it's used here, instead it should be used like `typeof timeout == "null"`, but the problem is that even such a syntax would be completely invalid, because even if it was null, it wouldn't evaluate to "null", it would evaluate to "object", just try pasting the following JavaScript into a console:

```
typeof null
```

It should say "object", even `typeof undefined` is "undefined", which is a string, which, when put in an if statement, would still evaluate to `true` relatively speaking, so the if statement checking if timeout is defined or not was done completely wrong.

Instead, that if statement should simply be changed to `if(timeout)`, removing `typeof` completely.

Answer (score 0):

typeof will return the type of the variable you put inside.

These are some types in JavaScript

1. number
2. string
3. boolean
4. array
5. object
6. undefined

you can use the type as

```
let s1 = 'somevalue'
cosole.log(typeof(s1)) // prints 'string'
```

you can play around with that and change the contents of s1. Now to the comparing part, if you try something like

```
if(typeof(s1)=='number')
 dothis()
else if (typeof(s1)=='string')
 dothat()
```

tip : both are same

```
typeof s1
```

```
typeof(s1)
```

and typeof(typeof(someVar)) is always string, that's why the == operator works

Hope it helped and didn't confuse you further.